# SPRINGBOOT- Reading textile as input stream. Null pointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

Im trying a dictionary text file and return said result if the word is found or not. But its not reading it I've been trying to find solutions for 3 days. Ive tried moving my dictionary file to main/java and using get class.get resource. Below is my code

```
public static HashSet <String> DoesWordExist(int ReviewScore, String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            
            
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        
        try (var resource = Review.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/dictionary/dictionary.txt")){
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(resource)) {
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                     set.add(sc.next());
                           // Reading dictionary
                              if (set.contains (s)) { // Checking word is in dictionary
                            
                              }
                        else {
                            ReviewScore -= 5;
                            System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore); // each word that is not found due to either typo or non-existence deduct 5pts
                        }
                        
                    }
            } 
            }
                
            catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return set;

        }
```

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMZX.png)

Comment: Nothing being added to the empty Set...

Comment: My bad. Im a beginner. Thank you, I added to the set but Im still receiving the same error. Will update my code

Comment: Your `if` block is empty. What are your intentions? A method called `doesWordExist` (method names begin lower case in Java) implies a `boolean` return value, yet you return the `Set` you filled...

Comment: Im trying to use the hash set to store the dictionary text file and read from it to check if the words (String s) are in the set aka the dictionary. If the word is in there the score should stay the same (why I left it empty) else the score should decrease by 5. I was prompted by eclipse to remove the void which I meant I had to add a return statement.

Comment: Then you need to return the new review score. You can't alter the one you pass as Java passes parameters by value. You *could* pass a `Review` object and have the method act upon its 'score' attribute. At the moment, be aware that 5 is being subtracted for every word in the dictionary until `s` is found. And the algorithm is possibly otherwise dubious